# When heat is applied to the top of a stack of pennies, why does the bottom penny melt first?

Tags: thermodynamics, metals

I just watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r16U7zEFCbI) where a blow torch is used on the top of a stack of pennies.

[image]

[image]

I'd like to know why the bottom penny melted first.

Comment: The pennies are mainly zinc with a copper plating.  When you heat them the copper will remain unmelted while the zinc inside melts.  All the pennies melt internally, but the one the bottom collapses from the weight and expels its zinc first.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would suggest that the bottom penny does not have the same composition. A zinc penny is mentioned in the comments (BTW, what a tedious video) and zinc has a *much* lower melting point than copper (420 C vs 1085C). Copper plated zinc pennies were introduced in 1982. Given that it started to melt almost straight away, I think that is your answer.

At about 10 mins onwards in the video you can clearly see from the brightness of the top penny that it appears to be much hotter than those below. Heat conduction can only follow the temperature gradient, so even if the bottom penny was on an insulating surface it couldn't actually get hotter than the penny above it.

EDIT: Something similar has gone on in the UK and is equally illegal). The two-pence coin weighs 7g and was, pre-1992, made of bronze (about 95% copper) and was replaced with copper-plated steel. At peak copper prices, the pre-92 coin was worth significantly more than its face value as scrap metal (I just checked, you could still get 0.3p per gramme). You could also sort out a pile of two pence pieces into pre- and post-92 coins with a magnet - a nice magnetism demonstration, for which I used to have a set of coins from 1975-2010 in a row that you could pass a Neodymium magnet over.

Comment: That would be my guess as well.  In other news, the amount of propane that he used to heat up those pennies almost certainly exceeds the value of the copper.

Comment: @RobertHarvey For sure, and it didn't even work (and is probably illegal).

Comment: @100% illegal, but interesting to think about nonetheless. Reportedly, those pennies are worth 1.8 cents as scrap. I'm not sure how many of those pennies there are in circulation, but theoretically some wealthy person could cash in all of his money for pennies and nearly double his worth. Illegally. Theoretically. With a more efficient melting method.. Well, it's a long shot..

Comment: Also, please read the description of the video: "A post 1982 penny must've made it into the stack".

Comment: Those are US pennies, and in the US destroying *coins* (as opposed to bills) is [only illegal if intended for fraud](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/5714). You can't mint your own coins, or debase the currency by taking a little bit of the metal out of a coin, but you can completely destroy the coins.

Comment: @ChrisWhite can you confirm that what I think I remember hearing in a TV show episode on the topic, "Melting down pennies for scrap value is illegal" is false, then?

Comment: http://www.usmint.gov/pressroom/?action=press_release&ID=771 - 2006/7 - `The United States Mint today announced a final rule to limit the exportation, melting, or treatment of one-cent (penny) and 5-cent (nickel) United States coins, to safeguard against a potential shortage of these coins in circulation.` ... `Specifically, the newly enacted final regulation prohibits, with certain exceptions, the exportation, melting or treatment of one-cent and 5-cent coins.`

Comment: Canada - one step ahead by eliminating the penny. Also, makes making change so much easier.

Comment: @WernerCD See [this pdf](https://www.usmint.gov/downloads/consumer/FederalRegisterNotice.pdf): "The prohibition contained in § 82.1 against the treatment of 5-cent coins and one-cent coins shall not apply to the treatment of these coins for educational, amusement, novelty, jewelry, and similar purposes as long as the volumes treated and the nature of the treatment makes it clear that such treatment is not intended as a means by which to profit solely from the value of the metal content of the coins." "Treatment" is defined in 82.3.e to include smelting.

Comment: @CuriousProgrammer See my above comment. It's illegal as a profit-making enterprise on a large scale, but not for individuals doing frivolous things on a small scale.

Comment: This can easily be confirmed by looking at the molten metal coming out of the bottom of the stack, which is grey.  Molten copper would be the same pinkish-orange colour as solid copper, assuming, of course, that it's illuminated brightly enough to outshine the intense incandescence that is produced at the temperatures needed to melt copper.  Since the liquid is a) grey, and b) not glowing, it must be a metal that is contained in at least some U.S. pennies, and is not copper.  I.e., zinc.